# Applescript to "paste" clipboard

Tags: macos, applescript, voiceover

I am working on an Applescript to paste what was last copied to any current field. It is to be used with VoiceOver and the key code way (only way I know how) does not work all of the time.

```
    tell application "System Events" to key code 9 using command down

    say "paste"
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I use keystroke:

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down
```

I'm not aware of an error you should get, so you'll have to share.

Comment: Also, when using UI scripting to copy and past the clipboard, I put in delays to help keep the script from tripping over itself.  delay .2

Comment: Note that this won't work if you are holding down other modifiers while this occurs. Any keys you are pressing are added to the modifiers used; e.g., if holding the Option key, then this will do "cmd-opt-v" which likely won't work.

Answer (score 6):

There is a direct way to access the clipboard via the [**`the clipboard`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW28) keyword:

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to keystroke (the clipboard as text)
```

Reference:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW28

Answer (score 1):

```applescript
tell application "myApp" to activate

tell application "System Events" to tell application process "myApp"
    click menu item "Paste" of menu "Edit" of menu bar item "Edit" of menu bar 1
end tell
```

Obviously, replace `myApp` with the name of your app.

#### Advantages:

- Only targets a specific app (safer!)
- Will work even if the user set a custom keyboard shortcut for `Paste`
- Text is pasted instantly (unlike using `keystroke`).